# NetBeans java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver

Tags: java, netbeans, rxtx

I am trying to run the code given below:

```
   package serialiotest;

    import gnu.io.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;

    public class SerialIOTest 
    {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
        System.out.println("Starting");
        java.util.Enumeration<CommPortIdentifier> portEnum 
                = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

        while (portEnum.hasMoreElements())
            {
            CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier
                    = portEnum.nextElement();

            System.out.println(portIdentifier.getName() + " - "
                + getPortTypeName(portIdentifier.getPortType()));
            }
        } 

    static String getPortTypeName (int portType )
        {
        switch(portType)
            {
            case CommPortIdentifier.PORT_I2C:
                return "I2C";
            case CommPortIdentifier.PORT_PARALLEL:
                return "pParallel";
            case CommPortIdentifier.PORT_RAW:
                return "RAW";
            case CommPortIdentifier.PORT_RS485:
                return "RS485";
            case CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL:
                return "Serial";
            default:
                return "unknown type";
            }
        }
    }
```

The error message generated is:

```
      run:
      Starting
      java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:  
           no rxtxSerial in ava.library.path    
           thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver
      Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
           no rxtxSerial in java.library.path
           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864)
           at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
           at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
           at gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier.<clinit>
              (CommPortIdentifier.java:123)
           at serialiotest.SerialIOTest.main(SerialIOTest.java:16)
           Java Result: 1
           BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

The build output is:

```
          ant -f /home/crazyprof/NetBeansProjects/serialIOTest   
                -Dnb.internal.action.name=rebuild clean jar
          init:
    deps-clean:
    Updating property file: /home/crazyprof/NetBeansProjects/serialIOTest
       /build/built-clean.properties
    Deleting directory /home/crazyprof/NetBeansProjects/serialIOTest
       /build
    clean:
    init:
    deps-jar:
    Created dir: /home/crazyprof/NetBeansProjects/serialIOTest/build
    Updating property file: /home/crazyprof/NetBeansProjects/serialIOTest
      /build/built-jar.properties
    Created dir: /home/crazyprof/NetBeansProjects/serialIOTest/build  
      /classes
    Created dir: /home/crazyprof/NetBeansProjects/serialIOTest/build
      /empty
    Created dir: /home/crazyprof/NetBeansProjects/serialIOTest/build
      /generated-sources/ap-source-output
    Compiling 1 source file to /home/crazyprof/NetBeansProjects
      /serialIOTest/build/classes
    Note: /home/crazyprof/NetBeansProjects/serialIOTest/src/serialiotest
      /SerialIOTest.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    compile:
    Created dir: /home/crazyprof/NetBeansProjects/serialIOTest/dist
    Copying 1 file to /home/crazyprof/NetBeansProjects/serialIOTest/build
    Copy libraries to /home/crazyprof/NetBeansProjects/serialIOTest
          /dist/lib.
    Building jar: /home/crazyprof/NetBeansProjects/serialIOTest
      /dist/serialIOTest.jar
    To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
    java -jar "/home/crazyprof/NetBeansProjects/serialIOTest
       /dist/serialIOTest.jar"
    jar:
    BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 23 seconds)
```

I am new to Ubuntu 14.04 so answers will have to be fairly detailed.

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite clear rxtx native libraries are not in your java.library.path. There are many ways to add them to your java.library.path:

- You can add them by placing the right *.so files in a folder and then add the `-Djava.library.path=folder` to your java command.
- You can just place the *.so files in your JAVA_HOME/lib/(amd64/i386) folder. Although I don't recommend this one because it is messy

If you've already done that, you can check if your libraries have some dependency missing by executing `ldd` command on your *.so.

Comment: Mr. Martinez:  I am thanking you.  I will try and see what happens.